# How to add a custom DataType in Sequelize ORM

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I want to define a custom data type in `Sequelize` by inheriting all default behaviours of existing `DataType.Integer`. The base idea here is to define a new type and override `valueOf` and `toString` methods.

The Sequelize docs doesn't contain any information related to this topic. It would be really nice if someone can help me on this.

Comment: [Sequelize v5 documentation](https://sequelize.org/v5/manual/data-types.html#extending-datatypes)

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/master/lib/data-types.js holds the sequelize data types.

Specifically, https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/master/lib/data-types.js#L251-L273 shows how DataTypes.INTEGER inherits from DataTypes.NUMBER using `NUMBER.inherits(fn)`.

Those inherit from ABSTRACT. You could override the `toString()` method for your inherited data type like as seen at https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/master/lib/data-types.js#L62-L64.

Disclaimer: with it not being publicly documented, I am not sure how stable the APIs are and would be cautious due to possible future changes.

Answer (score 1):

In v6, Sequelize provides a guide, with code examples, on how to do this. It is similar to the solutions already provided, but I thought it should be added here for completeness.

https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/other-topics/extending-data-types/

Answer (score 0):

To extend DataTypes in Sequelize:

```
class DataTypes_IP extends DataTypes.ABSTRACT {
  constructor () {
    super()
    this.key = 'IP'
  }

  toSql() {
    return 'VARBINARY(16)'
  }

  // Todo
  validate (value) {
    // const Validator = require('./utils/validator-extras').validator 
    // if (!Validator.isDate(String(value))) {
    //   throw new sequelizeErrors.ValidationError(util.format('%j is not a valid date', value)) 
    // }
    return true 
  }

  _sanitize (value) {
    return new IP(value) 
  } 

  _isChanged (value, originalValue) {

    if (value === originalValue) return false
    if (
      value instanceof IP && 
      originalValue instanceof IP && 
      value.toBuffer().equals(originalValue.toBuffer()) 
      ) {
      return false
    }
    return true
  } 

  _stringify (ip) {
    return ip.toBuffer() 
  } 
}
```

And extends the DataTypes

```
DataTypes.IP = DataTypes_IP
```

You can check the relevant issue in github.
https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/8533